# Python multiprocessing - sharing large dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing, large-data

I'm trying to speed up a CPU-bound Python script (on Windows11). Threats in Python do not seem to run on a different cpu(core) so the only option I have is multiprocessing.

I have a big dictionary data structure (11GB memory footprint after loading from file) that I am checking calculated values on if they are in that dictionary. Input for the calculation also comes from a file (100GB in size). This input I can pool-map to the processes in batches, no problem. But I cannot copy the dictionary to all processes because there is not enough memory for that. So I need to find a way for the processes to check if the value (actually a string) is in the dictionary.

Any advice?

Pseudo programm flow:

```
--main--
- load dictionary structure from file   # 11GB memory footprint
- ...
- While not all chuncks loaded
-    Load chunk of calcdata from file   # (10.000 lines per chunk)
-    Distribute (map) calcdata-chunck to processes
-    Wait for processes to complete all chunks

--process--
- for each element in subchunk
-    perform calculation
-    check if calculation in dictionary  # here is my problem!
-    store result in file
```

Edit, after implementing comments below, I am now at:

```
def ReadDictFromFile()
    cnt=0
    print("Reading dictionary from " + dictfilename)
    with open(dictfilename, encoding=("utf-8"), errors=("replace")) as f:
        next(f) #skip first line (header)
        for line in f:
            s = line.rstrip("\n")
            (key,keyvalue) = s.split()
            shared_dict[str(key)]=keyvalue
            cnt = cnt + 1
            if ((cnt % 1000000) == 0): #log each 1000000 where we are
                print(cnt)
                return #temp to speed up testing, not load whole dictionary atm
    print("Done loading dictionary")        


def checkqlist(qlist)
    print(str(os.getpid()) + "-" + str(len(qlist)))
    
    for li in qlist:
        try:
            checkvalue = calculations(li)
        
            (found, keyval) = InMem(checkvalue)
                
            if (found):
                print("FOUND!!! " + checkvalue + ' ' + keyvalue)            
        except Exception as e:
            print("(" + str(os.getpid()) + ")Error log: %s" % repr(e))
            time.sleep(15)


def InMem(checkvalue):
    if(checkvalue in shared_dict):
        return True, shared_dict[checkvalue]
    else:
        return False, ""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()

    global shared_dict 
    manager = Manager()
    shared_dict = manager.dict()

    ReadDictFromFile()

    chunksize=5
    nr_of_processes = 10
    with open(filetocheck, encoding=("utf-8"), errors=("replace")) as f:
        qlist = []
        for line in f:
            s = line.rstrip("\n")
            qlist.append(s)
            if (len(qlist) >= (chunksize * nr_of_processes)):
                chunked_list = [qlist[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(qlist), chunk_size)]
                try:
                    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
                        pool.map(checkqlist, chunked_list, nr_of_processes)          #problem: qlist is a single string, not a list of about 416 strings.  
                except Exception as e:
                    print("error log: %s" % repr(e))
                    time.sleep(15)
    logit("Completed! " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y"))
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: if there's any natural structure for the "dictionary" then you could use that to index the processes.  you'd need to look after the processes yourself, but it might work.  otherwise, maybe use WSL, then you could use fork based parallelism and it might just work?

Comment: @SamMason using forked subprocesses will end up copying the data anyway, since just touching data in Python is a "write" (due to reference counting). This is sometimes avoidable if you are working with something like `array.array` or  a `numpy.ndarray` where you are working with some wrapper over a primitive buffer, so only the wrapper gets copied, but that is usually pertty tenuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a [multiprocessing.Manager.dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager) for this, it's the fastest IPC you can use to do the check between processes in python, and for the memory size, just make it smaller by changing all values to None, on my pc it can do 33k member checks every second ... about 400 times slower than a normal dictionary.

```py
manager = Manager()
shared_dict = manager.dict()
shared_dict.update({x:None for x in main_dictionary})
shared_dict["new_element"] = None  # to set another value
del shared_dict["new_element"]  # to delete a certain value
```

you can also use a dedicated in-memory database for this like redis, which can handle being polled by multiple processes at the same time.

@Sam Mason suggestion to use WSL and fork may be better, but this one is the most portable.

Edit: to store it in children global scope you have to pass it through the initializer.

```py
def define_global(var):
    global shared_dict
    shared_dict = var
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
...

    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=define_global, initargs=(shared_dict ,)) as pool:
```

Comment: Thats very interesting. In my  case the dict in filled once and the process just check if it is in the dict. {if (x in shared_dict):}. So no updating. The strange thing I get when trying to implement is "NameError shared_dict is not defined" from the processes. Not sure why at this moment.

Comment: @Hasse you have to pass it as an argument to the called function, or pass it in the initializer and store it in the global scope, as children don't "inherit" global variables from the parent process, when you pass it as argument to the children, it will not be copied.

Comment: Yes, I read that that is once again different on windows (just like fork). I'm just not sure how to do that when using map. See code update above. with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool: pool.map(checkqlist, qlist)  -> checkqlist is the process function, and qlist is a list that should be mapped over all processes. If I add shared_dict as argument, what would map do with that?

Comment: @Hasse i edited the answer to show how it can be transferred to the children's global scope, keep in mind this is an IPC object, there is only 1 of it in memory, the children just get references to the owning process, but don't copy the memory to themselves.

Comment: Great lessons in multiprocessing here! It starts to get together. At least it's running without errors. Somehow the map function only sends one string to a process and not a list. So now I have 1 process starting per line in my file. The overhead of that is extreme. So I need to figure out that mapping thing in more detail. But the multiprocessing works and has become much more clear to me now! Thanks!

Comment: @Hasse you can change the `chunksize` parameter of pool.map to get some speedup if you are limited by "one line at a time" part, it reduces some of the transfer overhead if the lines you are transferring are small, but you have a lot of benchmarking to do, and there are a lot of multiprocessing profiling tools that can help you.

Comment: No, it's not the chucksize (amount of cpu's is good for now. but also tried 10, same results). My checkqlist(qlist) function seems to only get one element from map. I have 10.000 elements and 24 cpu's, so I expected my function to get a list of 10.000/24=416 elements. In stead it gets 1. Not sure why this happens yet.

Comment: I updated my code to show the problem with map.

Comment: @Hasse it's not a problem, it's how map works, you have to split the work yourself into a list of lists, and each list will be passed to a worker.

Comment: Still struggling here with the mapping. When I create for example a list of 10 lists containing 5 elements each and map that to 10 processes, the result is that there is just 1 (!) process created, receiving 10 times a list of 5 elements.... I want it to start 10 processes, processing 5 elements each. (using small numbers and debug output to check it). Updated code above with it.

Comment: Just found out that I have to leave out the amount_of_processes parameter from the pool.map function. I guess it takes the amount of processes from the list of lists size. But still dont understand why it acts this strange if I make it explicit....

Comment: @Hasse set the chunksize parameter to 1